# NTP synchronization is not happening continuously

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ntp, ntpd

I am working on a NTP client(Linux PC) to synchronize the time from NTP server(Linux PC). The NTP server in turn will synchronize the time from router.

Router <- NTP server(Linux Machine) <- NTP client(Linux Machine)

My issue is when we power on the complete setup at a time, NTP client fetches/updates its date/time from NTP server before the NTP server update its date/time from Router.
I know we can restart the NTP service and force reset date/time using NTP commands in NTP client using ntpdate/"ntpd -gq". But I am not using any commands.

**Is there any way that NTP client can fetch and update the date and time from NTP Server continuously every 30seconds automatically using ntpd service?**

I configured NTP client to get the time from NTP server in /etc/ntp.conf:
server <SERVER_IP> iburst
Because of this issue the NTP client's date/time is always not in sync with NTP server/Router.

Comment: Are you asking how to configure the NTP client on Windows? If so, I suggest superuser.com or if this is a professional setting (seems to be), serverfault.com.

Comment: Your question makes it sounds like you are coding your own NTP server?  If not which one are you trying to configure?  Both "ntpd" and "chrony" automatically update every two minutes or faster if your system clock's jitter is a mess.  systemd-timesync is an SNTP client (so much less accurate) but this too synchronises periodically to ensure the time is kept correct.

Comment: NTP server and NTP client are linux systems. I am using ntpd service in both client and server. NTP client is able to fetch date/time only after boot up which is only once. Later if I change the time in NTP server, the NTP client is not getting the updated date/time in NTP server.

Comment: Do any of these devices have real time clocks? And you use ntpdate to set the clocks before turning on or restarting ntp? Also, do you run ntpdate multiple times until the ntpdate indicates the maximum time resolution has been obtain? Where does the router get it's time from?

Comment: @CinaedSimson why should you run `ntpdate` before turning on NTP?

Comment: Yes, RTC is there in all the devices. I don't run any commands like ntpdate or  "ntpd -gq".
Actually I just configured NTP client to get the time from NTP server in /etc/ntp.conf like below:
server <SERVER_IP> iburst

Comment: I think you need to be much clearer in your question about what you have installed so far and what you have configured.  `ntpd` automatically updates your clock up to 90 seconds apart.  It does NOT just update it on startup.

Comment: And just to be clear `NTP` (in capitals) is the name of the protocol. `ntp` or `ntpd` (lower-case) is the name of one specific piece of software implementing that protocol.

Comment: @PhilipCouling some systems (principally the Raspberry Pi family) don't have an RTC so one has to call `ntpdate` or use `ntpd -gG`. This is usually done automatically as part of system start-up, along with an assumption that saving the datestamp on shutdown will give a bearable approximation for initial startup

Comment: @roaima Is `ntpd` incapable of functioning if started with a wildly incorrect clock?  My query is really why you would do this on a system with an enabled NTP daemon?

Comment: @PhilipCouling there's a threshold beyond which `ntpd` will refuse to synchronise unless you insist you know what you're doing. It's intended to stop reasonably correct systems accidentally synchronising to a wildly wrong one. (Which is why you should have an odd non-single number of upstream servers.)

Comment: @roaima I suspect that is the information the OP is lacking rather than the instruction to "run it once".  Bringing up a chain of devices as the OP describes is prone to synchronise the system clock to a point years in the past (see my final [note](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645362/20140)).  If this happens `ntpd -gG` will be executed once on statup and leave the system years in the past and unable to use `ntp` going forward.

Comment: True. Especially with your comment about the BT HH (I didn't realise it was braindead, but I don't use one). Mind, I didn't think I had anything sufficient to add as an Answer that wasn't already covered by you in yours

Comment: @PhilipCouling ntpdate and ntp both use the same ntp network socket - and only one those can use it at a time. Order doesn't matter. ntpdate has the advantage there is no limit on how much the clock can be adjusted - years if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Something about this question doesn't quite add up.

By default Ubuntu uses [systemd-timesyncd](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp).  I believe it's default configuration uses a dedicated NTP server pool from [ntp.org](http://www.ntp.org/).

Systemd-timesyncd is an SNTP client which is less precise than an NTP client but good enough for most end-user machines.  This will periodically poll for the time automatically.  So on this point your question does not make much sense.

However (I believe) the default maximum interval is just over half an hour (2048 seconds).  So if the clock synchronises incorrectly on startup it could be quite a up to 30 minutes before it corrects itself.  You can reduce this time with the `PollIntervalMaxSec` configuration in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`.  See the manual...  at the command line type [`man 5 timesyncd.conf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/timesyncd.conf.5.html).

---

Note that by default systemd-timesyncd is setup to accept time servers given out over [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol).  This can cause them to add the router as a direct NTP server as well as taking your NTP server.

---

Note that a well configured NTP server should not cause problems with this, it should refuse to give a valid time to NTP clients until it's own clock has synchronised correctly.

**However** home routers can do bad things on NTP.  I've personally witnessed home routers with no internal clock (BT Home Hub) respond to clients claiming to be [stratum 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Clock_strata) and will do so even before they synced anything.  The result of that is that rebooting the router sets clocks on the network back to a fixed date for a few minutes.